# What is the compression algorithm used in TDengine? Can I configure it by myself?

Tags: database, tdengine

I have found that there's a good performance in Time-Series data compression in TDengine. What is the compression algorithm used in TDengine? Can I configure it by myself?
I found there's a configuration "comp = 0/1/2" in taos.cfg

Answer (score 0):

TDengine provides three compression options: no compression, one-stage compression and two-stage compression, corresponding to **comp** values of 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

One-stage compression is carried out according to the type of data. Compression algorithms include delta-delta coding, simple 8B method, zig-zag coding, LZ4 and other algorithms.

Two-stage compression is based on one-stage compression and compressed by general compression algorithm, which has higher compression ratio.